# how to create unsigned type columns in TDengine

Tags: tdengine

I was using tdengine, i don't if tdengine supports unsigned type. And i tried to create unsigned type like this.

> taos> create table test(ts timestamp,unsigned int uint);
>
> DB error: syntax error near "unsigned int uint);" (0.001150s) taos>
> create table test(ts timestamp,uint unsigned int );
>
> DB error: syntax error near "unsigned int );" (0.000809s)

Does anyone knows that if tdengine supports the unsigned type? If it does please give some example.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes, TDengine supports the unsigned data type. you can create unsigned data type as follow sql:

```
create table unsigntest(ts timestamp,ut tinyint unsigned,us smallint unsigned,ui int unsigned,ub bigint unsigned,bi bigint);
```

Comment: this is useful thank you